# How to store a big float64 in a string without overflow?

Tags: go, overflow, transfer

```
func main() {
        target := 20190201518310870.0
        fmt.Println(int64(target))
        z3 := big.NewInt(int64(target))
        fmt.Println(z3)
}
```

The result is 20190201518310872

How do I convert it and not make overflow?

Comment: Check out the `strconv` package that exists in the standard library. `strconv.FormatInt` should be able to suit your needs

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that even your input `target` number is not equal to the constant you assign to it.

The `float64` type uses the [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (IEEE 754) to store the number, which has finite bits to utilize (64 bits in total, but only 53 bits are used to store the significand). This means it can roughly store ~16 digits, but your input number has 17, so it will be rounded to the nearest representable `float64`.

If you print `target`, you will see the exact number that is "transfered" to `big.Int`:

```
target := 20190201518310870.0
fmt.Printf("%f\n", target)
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EhE4zY_M4fN)):

```
20190201518310872.000000
```

Note that it works if the input constant "fits" into `float64`:

```
target := 20190201518310.0
fmt.Printf("%f\n", target)
fmt.Println(int64(target))
z3 := big.NewInt(int64(target))
fmt.Println(z3)
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qdeiUUZDTIo)):

```
20190201518310.000000
20190201518310
20190201518310
```

If you need to work with big numbers exactly such as `20190201518310870.0`, you have to use another type to store it in the first place, e.g. `string`, `big.Int` or `big.Float`, but not `float64`.

For example:

```
target := "20190201518310870"
fmt.Println(target)
z3, ok := big.NewInt(0).SetString(target, 10)
fmt.Println(z3, ok)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rVRKqimvPzq)):

```
20190201518310870
20190201518310870 true
```