# Is it expected behavior that Go allows overflow for arithmetic operations instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: go, integer-overflow

I am porting some Go code to Rust and I realized that Rust panics when overflow occurs during multiplication while Go allows the overflow to happen.

Test code below, that does not cause overflow but print reduced value. 
(tested via: https://play.golang.org/)

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("test\n")
    var key uint64 = 15000;

    key = key*2862933555777941757 + 1

    fmt.Println(key)
}
```

Comment: No, as you've proven yourself, it does not. Numbers are truncated at the boundary of the data type they're stored in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Spec: Integer overflow:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_overflow)

> For unsigned integer values, the operations +, -, *, and << are computed modulo 2<sup>n</sup>, where *n* is the bit width of the [unsigned integer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)'s type. Loosely speaking, **these unsigned integer operations discard high bits upon overflow, and programs may rely on "wrap around"**.
>
> For signed integers, the operations +, -, *, /, and << may legally overflow and the resulting value exists and is deterministically defined by the signed integer representation, the operation, and its operands. **Overflow does not cause a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics).** A compiler may not optimize code under the assumption that overflow does not occur. For instance, it may not assume that `x < x + 1` is always true.

As quoted above, overflow exists and it does not cause a run-time panic.

But care must be taken, as if you have a [constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions), since they have arbitrary precision, if the result is to be converted to a fixed precision where it does not fit into the target type's valid range, it results in a compile time-error.

For example:

```
const maxuint64 = 0xffffffffffffffff
var key uint64 = maxuint64 * maxuint64

fmt.Println(key)
```

The above yields:

```
constant 340282366920938463426481119284349108225 overflows uint64
```

`maxuint64 * maxuint64` is a constant expression which is properly calculated (its value is `340282366920938463426481119284349108225`), but when this value is to be assigned to the `key` variable of type `uint64`, it results in a compile-time error because this value cannot be represented by a value of type `uint64`. But this is not a run-time panic.

See related questions:

[Golang: on-purpose int overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704843/golang-on-purpose-int-overflow/34704898#34704898)

[Does Go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372)

[How to store a big float64 in a string without overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477761/how-to-store-a-big-float64-in-a-string-without-overflow/54477914#54477914)

[Proper way for casting uint16 to int16 in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023473/proper-way-for-casting-uint16-to-int16-in-go/48023533#48023533)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Really appreciate that!

Comment: Might be worth noting that overflowing is perfectly fine in Rust as well if you compile for release rather than debug. There is [`u64::checked_mul()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html#method.checked_mul) if that is not desired.